# SQL Converting Minutes to Hour Increments

Tags: sql

I am trying to alter a table within a stored procedure that will convert the minutes (i.e. 15) to hour increments (i.e. 0.25). Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `minutes / 60.0` should do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Declare @minutes int = 15
SELECT @minutes / 60 + (@minutes % 60) / 60.0
```

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: it's for mssql but logic is the same all dbmses

Comment: Not if the dbms is doing integer division, which is quote common. (15 / 60 = 0)